# Can I use javascript with bottle (framework)?

Tags: javascript, python, bottle

I'm trying to display a page of html using bottle (the python web framework).  The page has javascript embedded but it won't display it when I serve it with bottle.

The JS I'm using is [EditArea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/?page=editArea), I can clean it up how I want and put it an html page that displays properly when I open the page in chrome.  But when I use bottle:

```
@route('/edit')
def edit():
    return template('editarea')


@route('/edit_area')
def edit_area():
    send_file('example1.html', root='path/to/file/')
```

and go to http://localhost:8080/edit or /edit_area, I see the page without any of the fancy javascript features.

Eventually I want to hook this up (EditArea is text area and I'll be using it to accept code which hopefully I'll be able to run... but that's a separate issue...), but right now all it's supposed to do is display the page and the javascript.  The JS is put in the html as simply as possible.  Those two blocks use different files but they are just copies of the same html file, one with .html and the other with .tpl extensions.

```
<title>EditArea - the code editor in a textarea</title> 
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"     src="../edit_area/edit_area_full.js"></script> 
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
        // initialisation
        editAreaLoader.init({
```

...and then it's all of the JS code (that I didn't write).

In the file to start the server I import: route, run, debug, template, request, send_file, and error from bottle; and sqlite3; but that's all.  Is there something else I should be including?

I've looked into the bottle documentation, and a few other places and it's either something really obvious that nobody bothers to write down or it's something that people just don't do...

I was looking at pyjamas (it keeps coming up with different combinations of search queries involving "python" and "javascript"), but it looks like that just converts python into javascript.  I don't think that's what I want b/c the javascript is already javascript...

Thanks for any insight you might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the template system included in Bottle called SimpleTemplate then it does not support multi line strings and the templates get compiled to executable Python bytecode. So its likely any Javascript would be stripped out.

The only way to include javascript in your page would be via script tags as you did for the "edit_area_full.js" file.

Comment: That makes sense, I was concerned about that and I had started looking into the other templates but I'm kind of looking at the mako, cheetah, and jinja2 all at the same time trying to see which one will show me some javascript first but that's not working.  Which template system do you recommend.  Again, I'm not just trying to show the javascript, I want to eventually accept input from it.  Thanks.

Comment: the Bottle's templage engine is quite minimal, i would suggest using jinja2. Anyway, a template is just an html file with some logic added, which, given a "context", renders to html, you can add javascript to it or whatever you would do in a regulat html file, it will just work the same. The only difference is that in a template you can use loops or conditions to build your html.

Comment: I'd have to agree with MatToufoutu but would also add that Jinja2 is also used in the Flask framework and is very similar to Django's own template engine so when you do learn Jinja2 you'll find that knowledge useful in other areas.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a view to serve static files, as described in [Bottle documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#static-files).

I suggest you to put all your static files (css, js, images) in a `static` folder next to your application. The view to serve static files would then look like this:

```
from bottle import static_file    

@route('/static/:filename:')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/')
```

You would then include your `.js` file like this (using the path you'll have choosen of course):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/edit_area/edit_area.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would add it's better to use Bottle's `get_url` function instead of hard-coding the paths. The link to the js will be broken if you mount your application under a directory (http://example.com/app/). So better use `src="{{ get_url('static', filename='edit_area/edit_area.js') }}"`.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work this way; the javascript still isn't being shown properly.  Just to be clear: the url I'm trying to look at localhost:8080/static/example.html right?  I don't want to just point to the JS file b/c the html has the settings and some call functions that I will want to use.  That brings up another issue: will I be able to accept input through this system?  I was thinking that I would put some python code in the template to accept the input.  Is there a good way to do that if I'm hosting a static html with some JS?

Comment: why not just integrating the html code containing the settings and function calls you mention to your template? regarding the input, as i said in the other answer's comments, a template is just html with logic added, you can still put a form in it if you wish.